# AspNet Identity Roles - Custom

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Minha aplicação possui grupos de usuários que são customizáveis, ou seja, o usuário final cria e coloca acesso a determinadas permissões.

Para isso, eu tenho meus cadastros

Modulo, Menu, Item, Opção

Modulo = Financeiro, Cadastro, etc
Menu = Contas, Configuração financeiro, etc
Item = Cliente, Contas a Pagar, etc
Opcao = Novo, Alterar, Excluir, Visualizar

Nesse projeto, utilizei ASP.NET MVC4 E Forms Authentication.
E para filtrar definir essas "ROLES" customizadas, tenho meu filtro customizável em meus controllers.

Não sei se ficou claro.

Agora tenho um novo projeto ASP.NET MVC5 e irei utilizar ASP.NET Identity para autorização e autenticação de meus usuários.

Gostaria de saber se o no novo Asp.net Identity Roles, eu tenho essas Roles customizáveis, ou também terei que faz esse filtro novamente.

Pois nos exemplos que vi até agora, a única forma de verificar a role, seria Autorize(Role="Nome Role")

Procurei outros exemplos de role, também a mesma forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira de estender *Roles* é diferente no ASP.NET Identity. Usa-se *Controllers* + uma classe `IdentityManager`:

```
public class IdentityManager
{
    RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(
        new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
        new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();


    public bool RoleExists(string name)
    {
        return _roleManager.RoleExists(name);
    }


    public bool CreateRole(string name, string description = "")
    {
        var idResult = _roleManager.Create(new ApplicationRole(name, description));
        return idResult.Succeeded;
    }


    public bool CreateUser(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        var idResult = _userManager.Create(user, password);
        return idResult.Succeeded;
    }


    public bool AddUserToRole(string userId, string roleName)
    {
        var idResult = _userManager.AddToRole(userId, roleName);
        return idResult.Succeeded;
    }


    public void ClearUserRoles(string userId)
    {
        var user = _userManager.FindById(userId);
        var currentRoles = new List<IdentityUserRole>();

        currentRoles.AddRange(user.Roles);
        foreach (var role in currentRoles)
        {
            _userManager.RemoveFromRole(userId, role.Role.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

A classe a ser estendida agora é a `IdentityRole`, e a classe que gerencia *Roles* é a `RoleManager`:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name, string description) : base(name)
    {
        this.Description = description;
    }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

A criação de uma *Role* fica assim:

```
var idManager = new IdentityManager();

success = idManager.CreateRole("Admin", "Global Access");
```

A implementação de exemplo é bastante extensa, e pode ser obtida aqui: https://github.com/TypecastException/AspNetExtendingIdentityRoles

Mais informações aqui: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/727054/ASP-NET-MVC-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-R

Comment: Eu vi esse link, mas aí fica a dúvida, eu ainda preciso passar nas minhas actions [Authorize(Roles="Minha Role")] ? Pois isso é customizável pelo cliente, não posso passar parametros fixos, no antigo forms authentication eu usava um filtro customizável, e agora no identity?

Comment: É o mesmo esquema: você deriva o `AuthorizeAttribute` e coloca toda a lógica dentro do método `AuthorizeCore`.